# how to create a temporary session for visitors without them logging into my website

Tags: php, sql, session-cookies

Php Am building a e-commerce website so I want to create a temporary session for each and every user who visits my website and then store the information in database? (Note: without him creating  an account)

Comment: This is not a code/tutorial writing service. Read [ask]

Comment: Sessions, by definition, are temporary. "..store the information" , what information? How do you want to store it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use session_start function to create session in PHP, then you can store information about visitor, this is sample PHP code using session

```
<?php
session_start();
// set user name
$_SESSION['user_name] = $_POST['user_name']
```